# Exclude input element from tab order in IE

Tags: html, vue.js, accessibility

In my vue.js-based Single Page Application I have a checkbox that is not visible. I have to set opacity to zero due to UX reasons. Unfortunately the input element is still part of the tab order. To solve this issue I am setting the tabindex to -1 and this works flawlessly in Chrome as well as in Safari, but in IE11 it is still part of the tab order. How I can safely exclude the invisible checkbox from the taborder to realize a fully accessible UI?

Comment: Have you tried setting `display: none` ? I believe that should take care of your problems. You won't even need the `tabindex` or `opacity`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately i have to rely on opacity as I have to avoid paint reflows in that particular case. Setting display: none nevertheless will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a bug with IE11 that causes endless frustration (normally with SVG images gaining focus they shouldn't).

The answer is to add the attribute `focusable="false"` to the checkbox. It isn't technically part of the spec (think it was an IE only thing) I don't think but it should cause you no issues.

I can see the use case for having opacity: 0 if you want to 'fade-in' the checkbox based on a particular setting / scenario, however if that isn't the case then `visibility: hidden` may be a much better option if you are unable to use `display: none`.

## Quick Reference

Use `display: none` if you can.

If not use `visibility: hidden` if you can.

If not (and you must use `opacity: 0`) then use `focusable="false"` as an attribute on the item.